# Python : can't extract correctly a csv file

Tags: python, csv, extract

I have to work in python with a csv file. He looks like this :

> 61979.521351 1 41 -91 2050
> 61979.521351 2 -10 -8 4
> 61979.526329 1 42 -96 2070
> 61979.526329 2 -17 -6 4
> 61979.531307 1 44 -88 2070
> 61979.531307 2 -12 -8 3
> 61979.536285 1 44 -101 2074
> 61979.536285 2 -13 -7 8
> 61979.541263 1 47 -99 2050

I don't know how to extract data from csv file when the data aren't separated by commas and when we don't have any header.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the delimiter and header parameters with:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('path_to_file', delimiter = ' ', header = None, names = colnames)
```

Here, colnames is a list with your desired column names

Answer (score 1):

In general:

```
d = ' '

with open('data.dat', 'r') as f:
    data = [x.split(d) for x in f.read().splitlines()]
```

You get a nested list with lines at top level and fields for bottom level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `csv` module thus:

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in rdr:
        # Remove or comment out the following line to keep each row element as a string:
        row = [float(elem) for elem in row]
        print(row)
```

Prints:

```
[61979.521351, 1.0, 41.0, -91.0, 2050.0, 61979.521351, 2.0, -10.0, -8.0, 4.0, 61979.526329, 1.0, 42.0, -96.0, 2070.0]
[61979.526329, 2.0, -17.0, -6.0, 4.0, 61979.531307, 1.0, 44.0, -88.0, 2070.0, 61979.531307, 2.0, -12.0, -8.0, 3.0]
[61979.536285, 1.0, 44.0, -101.0, 2074.0, 61979.536285, 2.0, -13.0, -7.0, 8.0, 61979.541263, 1.0, 47.0, -99.0, 2050.0]
```

**Update**

If you want to keep all the data as rows in a list where each element of a row can be indexed by a column name, then:

```py
import csv

column_names = list('ABCDEFGIHJKLMNO') # 'A', 'B', ... 'O'
data = []
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=column_names, delimiter=' ')
    data = [{k: float(v) for k, v in row.items()} for row in rdr]
    # Or: data = [row for row in rdr] # to keep everything as strings
print(data[2]['F'])
```

Prints:

```
61979.536285
```

The above offers a light-weight alternative to `pandas`.